# Optimize the display of graphics

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Currently, I have 6 graphics (0,1,2,3,4,5)...
My display below is great !

[image: six graphs]

My problem is that if the user has 3 graphics only for example 0, 2, and 5.
My graphics are not on a line, I don't know if you understand my explanation?

If you look the image, my graphics are not ordered on a line.

[image: six graphs ot ordered]

Do you think that the problem comes from HTML ?

```
<div class="container-adapt-h">    
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" [hidden]="!securities[0]?.historyExist">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <div id="chartdiveq0" style="width: 100%;height: 400px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" [hidden]="!securities[1]?.historyExist">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <div id="chartdiveq1" style="width: 100%;height: 400px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" [hidden]="!securities[2]?.historyExist">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <div id="chartdiveq2" style="width: 100%;height: 400px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
   
    <div class="container-adapt-h">  

        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" [hidden]="!securities[3]?.historyExist">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <div id="chartdiveq3" style="width: 100%;height: 400px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" [hidden]="!securities[4]?.historyExist">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <div id="chartdiveq4" style="width: 100%;height: 400px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" [hidden]="!securities[5]?.historyExist">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body p-0" >
                    <div id="chartdiveq5" style="width: 100%;height: 400px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am interested if you have an idea, else it's nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set `float: left` to the graph containers.

If there are few graphs -- the will align in one line. If there are more graphs -- the will flow to the next lines.

Comment: You will put `float:left` on `container-adapt-h` ? We are agree?

Comment: No, to these divs  `<div class="col-12 col-lg-4">`. You might need to remove cols-12 col-lg-4.

Comment: It work ! But, I have 5 graphics on a line. I would like to know if it is possible to have 3 graphics on a line? And 2 graphics on the second?

Comment: Set the width of the parent div to fit 3 graphs in a row.